# I can't run jupyterlab on vscode anymore

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I can no longer run jupyterlab with vscode, even though I used to be able to.
I get the following error.

```
Failed to start Jupyter in the environment 'Python 3.8.9 64-bit (/usr/bin/python3)'. 
View Jupyter log for further details.
```

The contents of the log are as follows.

```
Jupyter command `jupyter-notebook` not found.

    at t.JupyterConnectionWaiter.rejectStartPromise (/Users/###/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.1.1001821375/out/client/extension.js:51:519420)
    at t._complete (/Users/###/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.1.1001821375/out/client/extension.js:51:520072)
    at t.n (/Users/###/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.1.1001821375/out/client/extension.js:16:16688)
    at t.__tryOrUnsub (/Users/###/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.1.1001821375/out/client/extension.js:16:16930)
    at t.complete (/Users/###/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.1.1001821375/out/client/extension.js:16:16823)
    at t._complete (/Users/###/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.1.1001821375/out/client/extension.js:16:15287)
    at t.complete (/Users/###/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.1.1001821375/out/client/extension.js:16:14986)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/###/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2022.1.1001821375/out/client/extension.js:24:97233)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)] {
  category: 'jupyterconnection'
}
Info 17:32:27: Cancel pending cells
Info 17:32:27: Cell 0 executed with state Idle
Info 17:41:04: Loading webview. View is notset
Info 17:41:04: Loading web view...
Info 17:41:04: Webview panel created.
Info 17:41:04: Web view react rendered
Info 17:41:04: Searching for token colors ...
Info 17:41:04: Attempting search for colors ...
Info 17:41:04: Loading colors from /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/theme-defaults/themes/dark_plus.json ...
Info 17:41:04: Attempting search for colors ...
Info 17:41:04: Loading base colors from /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/theme-defaults/themes/dark_plus.json ...
Info 17:41:04: Using colors to generate CSS ...
Info 17:41:13: Disposing kernel .jvsc74a57bd01664e11304f2475fef880424b68b87feb8b6912b871e3b4aab1877d55b5690d2./Users/###/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/python./Users/###/.pyenv/versions/3.10.0/python.-m#ipykernel_launcher for notebook ~/Documents/BQConnect/quickstart_spreadsheet.ipynb due to selection of another kernel or closing of the notebook
Info 17:41:13: Dispose kernel file:///Users/###/Documents/BQConnect/quickstart_spreadsheet.ipynb
Info 17:41:13: Notebook Closed ~/Documents/BQConnect/quickstart_spreadsheet.ipynb
Info 17:41:13: Kernel got disposed as a result of closing the notebook file:///Users/###/Documents/BQConnect/quickstart_spreadsheet.ipynb
```

I can start jupyterlab itself.
Do you know how to start it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5NRC.png)

Comment: I had the same problem yesterday, I updated Jupyter extension and restarted Vscode it worked fine then.

Comment: Question (I work on this extension) what python env are you attempting to start? I see both 3.8.9 and 3.10.0 in the error messages? Wondering if the wrong kernel is attempting to be started.

From the error message it maybe looks like the target environment doesn't have jupyter installed correctly? Could try reinstalling that via either pip or conda.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't do anything but it worked.